# Unknown command: `repo-art` Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

I have installed the Cocoapods-art in the bundle using this command:

```
 bundle exec gem install cocoapods-art
```

This is the success message:

```
Fetching cocoapods-art-1.0.4.gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-art-1.0.4
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-art-1.0.4
Done installing documentation for cocoapods-art after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

when I execute: `bundle exec gem list`, I don't see Cocoapods repo-art in the gem list.

When I try to add: `pod repo-art add folderNamer`,  I get:

```
 [!] Unknown command: `repo-art`
Did you mean: repo?
```

Comment: Perhaps, `bundle exec pod repo-art add folderNamer`

Comment: Tried that as well I get same error : [!] Unknown command: `repo-art`
Did you mean: repo?

Comment: Are you running from the same directory where you did the `bundle exec gem install cocoapods-art`?

Comment: Samething is happening to me with `cocoapods-art-1.0.4`. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was:

Installing **cocoapods** by **gem** in MacOS Catalina + Xcode 12.2, I got the error:

```
You have to install development tools first 
...
checking for ffi.h... * extconf.rb failed *
```

Then I installed the **cocoapods** (1.10.1) by **homebrew**

```
brew install cocoapods
```

And the **cocoapods-art** was installed with **gem**

```
gem install cocoapods-art
```

At that moment, I was with the same error.

For me, its finally worked removing and installing again the **cocoapods-art** with `sudo`.

---

This troubleshooting - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668456 don't resolving to use the last version of cocoapods ;)

Answer (score 3):

for me works:
in console:

1. `brew uninstall cocoapods`
2. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. `sudo gem install cocoapods-art`
4. `pod repo-art add folderNamer`

Comment: Please don't repeat answers.

Comment: its isnt the same answer in my case cocapods-art dont work with brew cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error with `gem install cocoapods-art`. Then I used the command `sudo gem install cocoapods-art` and it worked :)